# It seems that almost all succesfull academics have had distinguished advisors. Is it really true that pedigree defines success?

Tags: phd, research-process, supervision

In his manuscript "The making of a scientist" [[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/2151441a0)], Hans Krebs highlighted the fact that great scientists are moulded for success by their renowned grad school advisors. Additionally, he talks about other things in the paper.

My question is, does the observation which Krebs made five decades ago still hold true? I was not lucky to get an inspiring PhD advisor during my PhD, in spite of my advisor having a really renowned PhD advisor. I did not learn anything substantially life changing (in matters of ethics, dedication, passion) from her apart from getting suggestions about my research. In such situation, should I just accept the fact that it is highly likely that I will never surmount to anything great in my future research career?

[[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/2151441a0)] Krebs, H. A. (1967). The making of a scientist. Nature, 215(5109), 1441.

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. Having a distinguished advisor and having a very successful career are correlated, but to a large extent I would think they are both effects of the same underlying cause (being very smart, talented and hardworking) rather than the latter being the effect of the former.

Comment: To extend on the comment of @DanRomik: Even causation doesn't mean single cause. Of course there is some influence of the advisor. If they are really great and passionate about their topic, they can easily motivate others. On the other hand, if they are bad at teaching and the classes are boring, that might demotivate some. But this is only one reason of many, other include, for example: your own intellect, personal circumstances, luck.

Comment: Two of my colleagues from uni had famous PhD advisors. Nothing special they learn they told me. It just mean that you have funding and a lot of possibility with them. How you will use it is up to you. That being said science is increasingly incremental so I don't think in current system any PhD student can learn alot. Friend that was in Nobel winning lab said she felt as she is just a small part of paper publishing machine

Comment: As with all education, there is presumably a multiplier effect, where the underlying talent and drive of a student combines with the great teaching (and perhaps extreme demands) of a renowned advisor, and produces a more successful student than either typically would on their own. For one thing the smarter the advisor, the more efficiently the student's time would be spent, for example on cutting-edge, yet solvable, open problems.

Comment: and is there a country somewhere that spells "succesfull" that way?

Comment: There is a quality selection effect more than a training effect.  By analogy, Harvard grads are what they are more because of the selection than because of the training.  In addition, if you are going to be a cutting edge R1 academic, you should at this point have some sense for the quality of different researchers...and some self evaluation of your capabilities.  You ought to be able to tell if you've "got it" regardless of the small school setting.  Instead of coming here for reassurance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a copy of the Krebs article, but I'm going to guess that he didn't mean to imply doom for every doctoral student who doesn't have a world renowned advisor. Your success is up to you and what you do, not some mythical inheritance from your legacy in academia.

Actually, I worry that if such a thing were true then scholarship would only  go down hill from wherever it started and never upward and outward. People who go beyond the the people who taught them are celebrated, actually, even by (especially by) those educators.

But, renowned people do have an advantage and they can pass part of that along to their students in some cases. If a person is a star in their field then lots of people want to work with them and they have lots of collaborative opportunities, even if they are often small ones. This means that there are a lot of ideas flying around in the presence of the luminaries and students can get into that sphere and exploit it. They can also exploit the contacts and build their own circle of collaborators.

But, it is also possible for people to form such rich research groups and seminars even when their own advisors are more modestly "endowed". Find ways to meet and interact with people who know more than you do and are willing to share it. In many fields, that means going to conferences and finding ways to participate there. You can also just correspond with people who might be able to help you put ideas together and focus your research.

But starting out with an attitude that you can't *really* succeed because your advisor wasn't in the very top ranks is something of a cop-out. If you really believe it, then it is a self fulfilling prophesy and you aren't likely to work hard enough to move upward in the estimation of your peers.

Work hard and swim in a sea of ideas, however you can make that happen. Luck helps too, of course. Others may have advantages, but that is true in everything.